# <option> returning emptyin UI form:select of spring mvc3

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-3

I've a list of values to be passed from my controller to the jsp page. I've the below controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addClient.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected ModelAndView Submit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    MyForm = new MyForm();


    MyForm.setClientList(MyService.getClientList(/*"30-JUN-15"*/));

    System.out.println("Size of list : "+MyForm.getClientList().size()); //-- Displayed as 10 which is correct

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("feeMaintenance");
    model.addObject("clientForm",MyForm);
    model.addObject("selectedMenu", "MenuSelected");
    model.addObject("clientsList",MyForm.getClientList());
    return model;
}
```

And my jsp form is as below:

```
<body>
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="clientForm" action="${userActionUrl}">
<tr>    <td align="left">
         <form:select path="clientList">  
            <form:option value="-" label="------Select Client ------">  
            <form:options items="${clientsLists}">  
        </form:options></form:option></form:select>  

</tr>   </td>
</form>
</body>
```

I've removed the additional unrelated code. The drop down only shows ----Select Client--- even though the controller shows the correct values of the clientList. Unable to figure out whats missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if MyForm.getClientList() is successfully return list of client data than
rewrite this line into jsp page.

you write key name into controller is **clientsList** and you write this into jsp page is **clientsLists** this is wrong.
I hope this is work.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.
model.addObject("country", projectservice.getallCountry());

**Note:**itemLabel name is same as property name into pojo class and also itemValue name.